# How to copy a line with fstream including white spaces?

Tags: copy, fstream, space

So if the file i was reading from contained:

2:Hello World

i would like for **num** to equal the number at the start of each line

and **text** equal the remaining string of the line

My question is how would i be able make it so my ifstream takes the entire line, including the spaces between words? instead of it taking only "Hello"

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  

   ifstream fin;
   fin.open(file);

   string s = "";
   fin >> s;

   loadPacket(s); 
}



void loadPacket(string s) {
   static const size_t npos = -1;
   num = pString.substr(0,1);
   text = pString.substr(4, npos);    
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the _exact_ format your input will be.